# Redirect loop on login

Tags: google-app-engine

I have troubles logging into a specific Google App Engine account owned by max@yogi.pw
Whenever I log in, the browser throws "too many redirects" error.
It happened after I transferred an application from obsolete account to new one:

1. I had a Google Apps account max@garygolden.me that owned the GAE application. That account had a sub-organization yogi.pw and the email was aliased to max@yogi.pw
2. I've signed up for new Google Apps for Business that has yogi.pw as primary domain
3. I've removed max@yogi.pw alias from max@garygolden.me and created an admin user max@yogi.pw on the new organization
4. I've granted ownership to max@yogi.pw for a GAE application

Since then I can't login to GAE.
And worse, max@garygolden.me no more owns the application, so I can't reach it from anywhere.

I'm sure this kind of mess requires manual configuration from Google support team.
I've seen this problem is common online, and Google engineers can do some magic when then are pointed to specific account.
Please, help!

P.S.: Yes, I've tried to clear cookies.

Comment: The question is not about programming, but how to use a google service.

Comment: @TimHoffman, you're probably not aware that appengine community support has moved to stackoverflow.

Comment: I am totally aware of that fact, however your question is not about programming, google reliance on SO specifically for server/application support is misplaced.  Read the charter for SO and how questions should be framed. You will also see in the google group for appengine these sort of question are discussed at length.

Answer (score 1):

Try visiting the following  from a private browsing session.

- https://appengine.google.com/
- https://cloud.google.com/console/project
- https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect

I have a personal & business account with Google and I've also had a lot of trouble.

Comment: Oh, thanks. The second and third URLs provided some level of control, but http://appengine.google.com still has redirect loop.
I am now able to create/delete projects though.